# sbt: how should a library depend upon scala-actors?

Tags: scala, sbt

We have an internal library that uses scala-actors 2.10.x.  It has this in its build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies <++= scalaVersion(v =>
  Seq("org.scala-lang" % "scala-actors" % v)
)
```

This library was only compiled with 2.10.0 and pushed to our internal Maven repo.

One of our projects that depends upon the library was updated to 2.10.1.  The dependent project has the same `libraryDependencies` so compiling the dependent project now warns:

```
$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /tmp/foo/project
[info] Set current project to bar (in build file:/tmp/foo/)
[warn] Potentially incompatible versions of dependencies of {file:/tmp/foo/}bar:
[warn]    org.scala-lang: 2.10.1, 2.10.0
```

Using the dependency sbt plugin shows this:

```
[info]   +-com.example:ourlibrary_2.10:1.0.1 [S]
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-actors:2.10.0 (evicted by: 2.10.1)
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.scala-lang:scala-actors:2.10.1 [S]
```

How should the library's `libraryDependencies` best be written?  I have the following, but is there a cleaner way?

```
libraryDependencies <++= scalaVersion(v =>
  {
    // Use any version of scala-actors for this version of Scala.
    val split = v.split('.')
    val major = split(0).toInt
    val minor = split(1).toInt
    val revision = "[%s.%s,%s.%s)".format(major, minor, major, minor+1)
    Seq("org.scala-lang" % "scala-actors" % revision)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala 2.10.x is guaranteed to be binary compatible, so whatever you're doing is fine. The Ivy seems to correctly evict `org.scala-lang:scala-actors:2.10.0`, so it shouldn't cause any problems.

In fact the warning message you mentioned is considered a bug [#709](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/709) and it should not be displayed in the recent releases of sbt 0.12 and 0.13.